# MySQL Increment a coloumn and inserting it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this.

```
Player_id  WeekNumber Point
1               1     5
1               2     10 
2               1     4
2               2     15
2               3     9
```

For example, I want to insert player 1's point for week 3. How can I do it? I can get max week number for player 1 and then increment it and I can save it. Is there any efficicent way?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into <<your table name goes here>> (Player_id, WeekNumber, Point)
select Player_id, ifnull(max(WeekNumber),0) + 1, <<point value goes here>>
from <<<your table name goes here>>
where Player_id = <<player id goes here>>
group by Player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit more clear:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Player_id,  WeekNumber, Point)
VALUES ($player_id, COALESCE((SELECT MAX(WeekNumber)
                             FROM table1 t2
                             WHERE Player_id=$player_id),0)+1, $points);
```